# Why does an oven burn out when all knobs are on?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

I'm having serious trouble understanding this. If a fuse burns out when too much current is flowing through it, then how does turning on all knobs to their full setting burn out the wall-plug?

Shouldn't turning on all knobs increase resistance as you're adding more components to the circuit? Can someone explain (in simple terms) why this happens, also referring to mains supply and wall plugs and series/parallel phenomena. A diagram would help too I guess.

Comment: The heating elements in an oven are wired in parallel, and when you connect resistors in parallel you decrease the total resistance and hence increase the current.